Change colorAccent according to theme for Android
In a MAUI project I want to adopt a different colorAccent value according to the theme of the application.
I tried to adopt this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241870/how-to-customize-coloraccent-when-changing-the-the, from the Xamarin.Forms era, with a small modification of the code in the MainActivity.cs:
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme);
    }
    else
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
    }
}

I also have set android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" property in the activity tag of AndroidManfest.xml, but the problem is that the execution of the code never enters the body of OnConfigurationChanged.
Is there another approach that works for MAUI?

In my test, the OnConfigurationChanged will be triggered when user change the theme of the device. In addition, the maui project's default theme is Splash theme, did you give up it?

What I change is Application.Current.UserAppTheme. I have placed the override of OnConfigurationChanged in MainActivity.cs. I have set break points in every single line of it. Definitely it does not get triggered. I also have set android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" property in the activity tag of AndroidManfest.xml. I will make an edit to add that detail too.


but the problem is that the execution of the code never enters the
body of OnConfigurationChanged.

The OnConfigurationChanged will be triggered when the system theme changed not the app's theme chanaged.
You can refer to the official document: User expectations of Runtime changes.
And if you want do something when change Application.Current.UserAppTheme. You can use Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged.
I used it in the MainActivity:
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
 {
     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     App.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, e) =>
     {
        if (Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
        {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme);
        }
    else
        {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        }
     };
 }

Edit:
You need to recreate the activity if you want to change its theme at runtime. And call the SetTheme() in the Activity's OnCreate method.

Delclare the custom color and custom style:

In the Platforms\Andorid\Resources\values\colors.xml:
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#512BD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccentDark">#FF0000</color>
</resources>

In the Platforms\Andorid\Resources\values\styles.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccentDark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccentDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentDark</item>
            <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorActionMenuTextColor</item>
            <item name="appBarLayoutStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
            <item name="bottomNavigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView</item>
            <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/MauiMaterialButton</item>
            <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/MauiCheckBox</item>
            <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
            <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MauiAlertDialogTheme</item>
      </style>
     
</resources>

In the MainActivity:
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
 public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
 {
     static bool IsDarkTheme = false;
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
     {
         App.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, e) =>
         {
             if(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.UserAppTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
                 IsDarkTheme = true;
             else
                 IsDarkTheme = false;
         };
         if (IsDarkTheme)
             SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme);
         else
             SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }   
 }

I used the static bool variable. You can use the preference to store the value instead.
Finally, recreate the activity when you change the theme:
            Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;
#if ANDROID
            Platform.CurrentActivity.Recreate();
#endif

In my test, the default theme [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme" will make the this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.DarkTheme); not work. If you change the SplashTheme to other theme, such as MainTheme, Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar and so on, the accent color will also change. But this will break the splash screen.

Well, we are halfway there. Indeed the listener gets triggered by the theme change. Yet the colorAccent does not change when the DarkTheme is selected. I'm using the approach that is selected as the Accepted Answer in this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241870/how-to-customize-coloraccent-when-changing-the-the and I have modified the Android > Resources > values > colors.xml file by adding a colorAccentDark entry and I also have created an Android > Resources > values > styles.xml Maybe this approach does not work with MAUI?

Please check the edited part in my answer. You can report this as a new issue on the github repo. @Costas

Regarding the splash screen in 3 different physical devices with Android 10, 12 and 13 I just get a purple empty splash screen and I only get the splash screen with the background color and the logo I have set when using the emulator (Android 14, but I have used an older version too with the emulator). That was the deal before switching to MainTheme and that's the deal after Switching to MainTheme. Nothing changed in my case.
(1/3)

But using MainTheme didn't fix the colorAccentDark issue too. The problem remains. Furthermore it overrides my settings for Shell's BackgoundColor  and Shell.TitleColor and introduces a new issue to deal with.
(2/3)

As an alternative of setting a colorAccentDark I could use a style for RadioButtons. If its possible to do it that way, that would be an acceptable solution for me too.
(3/3)

I have posted the full code and please check it. @Costas

I'm first trying another approach. I'm trying to use a ControlTemplate. If I will make it work I will adopt it, otherwise I will apply your solution.

Since I didn't test the last version of your code, I didn't hit the Accept button, but I upvoted your post.
As I said in my other question, I decided to apply a different style instead.

All right, using controltemplate is easier than changing the accent. Glad to know you have resolved this. @Costas
